# gumbyframework: responsive menu issue on smartphone

Tags: frameworks, menu, responsive-design

I'm developing a responsive website and i use the gumby framework http://gumbyframework.com/

Now, when i try to resize the window and the responsive menu appear, i click on the icon and it works. But if i try on a smartphone, nothing happen

this is the website i'm developing http://www.francescomigliorato.it/lachicca

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use version 1.8.3 of jquery. With the latest there is a problem with gumbyframework

Answer (score 0):

I notice in line 78 of main.js that you have a javascript error... I would fix that first and see what happens.

$('input.data').datepick({
    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepick'
        showTrigger: '#calImg'
    });

Comment: Seems like 'input.data' isn't a valid selector.

Comment: Actually, it looks like they updated the gumby.min.js file 5 days ago. Do you have the most recent? https://github.com/GumbyFramework/Gumby/blob/master/js/libs/gumby.min.js

Comment: Was a problem with the gumbyTap event.

Comment: I fixed the error of the firebug console. Can you try the site on a smartphone (if you have it) please? Thanks for your support

Comment: I tried it and, like you said it wasn't working. Can you follow the link I posted above and copy the new  version of the gumby.min.js over the one you are currently using?

Comment: Solved! The problem was the last version of jquery. With 1.8.3 it's ok. Thank you again @arnonate for your support